# Unable to find where transactions sent

Tags: lost-transactions

I sent this transaction and it took a long time to confirm as you can see
[023d90420161bbb5f97480d673405d19b79de1c4a7383c8977b62b16926d881c](https://tradeblock.com/bitcoin/tx/023d90420161bbb5f97480d673405d19b79de1c4a7383c8977b62b16926d881c).

Now I have asked the recipient and they have said that I used the wrong address. If that is the case. Where are my bicoin now please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very hard to do a typo in a Bitcoin address, as the address format includes a checksum. Have you checked whether you accidentally sent to a previous business partner? Have you checked whether the address that you sent to matches the address that you were asked to? If the latter is true the error may be on the side of the recipient.

In any case, the coins are now under the control of whomever the recipient address of the transaction belongs to. If

1. the address is unclaimed: the coins are lost.
2. the address is claimed by a known entity: you may be able to retrieve them by contacting them.
3. the address is claimed by an unknown entity: the recipient will do whatever they want.

Try googling the (unique!) respective address to see if someone is asking about receiving an unknown payment. It wouldn't be the first time. ;)

Comment: Makes sense. I think I will let them go and make some more :)

Answer (score 0):

If you used the wrong bitcoin address, your coins are gone. Your only hope is that the person that received them (if they did) sends your coins back to you (seems unlikely)

You should always check and double check the address you are sending to!

To be clear, if you used the correct address and the recipient is scamming you, there is also nothing you can do.

Answer (score -1):

I always get an address and a receipt their customer service which should be able to confirm where and what state or country it was don’t care who I just want to know where